# Run Python Script Every 5 min Between certain Hours

Tags: python

I have a python script that I would like to run every 5 minutes between the hours of 9am and 5pm. I do not want to use a crontab but rather automate the code within itself to run every five minutes. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715086/scheduling-python-script-to-run-every-hour-accurately

Comment: sched module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html