# How to make following code excute every 10 seconds

Tags: python

```
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')

page_content = page.read()

with open('index.html', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(page_content)
```

I have tried numerous things to get the code to run again after so many seconds but everything I try gives me errors(windows user)

```
import urllib2 
import time 
def executeSomething(): 
    page = urllib2.urlopen('127.0.0.1:5000/') 
    page_content = page.read() with open('index.html', 'w') as fid:
        fid.write(page_content) 
        time.sleep(60) 

while True: 
    executeSomething()
```

Comment: i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715086/scheduling-python-script-to-run-every-hour-accurately and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python maybe i just put the code in wrong

Comment: [code]import urllib2
import time

def executeSomething():
  page = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')

page_content = page.read()

with open('index.html', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(page_content)
 
    time.sleep(60)

while True:
    executeSomething()[/code]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can edit your question to add what you tried. This is better than posting it as a comment, as it gets more attention there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
import urllib2
import time

while True:
    page = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
    page_content = page.read()
    with open('index.html', 'w') as fid:
        fid.write(page_content)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: thank you so much..I was doing the order wrong

Comment: @NOnON You're welcome. If this answered your question, then you should accept the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158075)