# What do you use for running scheduled tasks in Production for Python?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, production, dev-to-production

The thing is, I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715086/scheduling-python-script-to-run-every-hour-accurately) stating best practices to set up a code to run at every specified interval over a period of time using the python library - APS Scheduler. Now, it obviously works perfectly fine if I do it on a test environment and run the application from the command prompt.

However, I come from a background where most my projects are university level and never ran in production but for this one, I would like to. I have access to AWS and can configure any kind of server on AWS and I am open to other options as well. It would be great if I could get a headstart on what to look if I have to run this application as a service from a server or a remote machine without having to constantly monitoring it and providing interrupts on command prompt.

I do not have any experience of running Python applications in production so any input would be appreciated. Also, I do not know how to execute this code in production (except for through aws cli) but that session expires once I close my CLI so that does not seem like the most appropriate way to do it so any help on that end would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was very simple and does not make a lot of sense and might not be applicable to all.

Now, what I had was a python flask application so I configured the app in a virtual environment using eb-virt on the aws server and then created an executable wsgi script which I then ran as a service using mod_wsgi plugin for the apache http server and then I was able to run my app.