# How to install apscheduler.schedulers with Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, anaconda

I'm using Python 3 & [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), running on [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/)

I have a function, let's call it `my_task`, which I want to run every day at `11am` and `11pm`.

```
def my_task():
    print("Hey, task is running!");
```

How can I do this?

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36410972/596841) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/596841) but neither of them is for Anaconda.

Comment: Why are they not for Anaconda? You can install pip packages with anaconda...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apscheduler` package discussed in the answer you linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715086/scheduling-python-script-to-run-every-hour-accurately/36410972#36410972) isn't, as you noted, in the main anaconda distribution but it is in the following conda [channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/apscheduler). This means that you can install it via `conda install -c conda-forge apscheduler=3.3.1` and use it.  I'd try installing with that and then following the procedures discussed in that other question/answer.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. `conda install -c conda-forge apscheduler=3.3.1` is indeed the correct answer.