# Run task on every 3rd and 8th minute in the day

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling

I would like to be able to run a task on the 3rd and 8th minute in the day between 7am-4pm local time. Also, it should only run Monday-Friday. I am writing this task in python and I am not sure what the best method of achieving this would be.

I do **not** have access to cron (it will run on windows), and I have looked at multiple schedulers including `apscheduler`  but unless I missed something I have not seen a way to achieve this.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715086/scheduling-python-script-to-run-every-hour-accurately) where they talk about `apscheduler`, in reading that, and in the documentation, I only see a way to schedule the task in intervals or for a future time, but not on an exact time of the day.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

**Example of times to run**

```
7:03-Run
7:08-Run
7:13-Run
7:18-Run
7:23-Run
7:28-Run
.
.
.
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use [apscheduler cron trigger type](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/cron.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.cron), with schedule like this [`3,8,13,18,23,28,3 7-16 * * 1-5`](https://crontab.guru/#3,8,13,18,23,28_7-16_*_*_1-5)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows equivalent of cron is [Scheduled Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7195722/10949095) post for an example of its usage.