# how to make a python script act every ten minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently run a Twitter bot. I want it to publish an image every ten minutes. I'm currently accomplishing this by using `time.sleep(600)`. This has led it to end up posting things at irregular intervals. However, I'm wanting it to publish an image every ten minutes like clockwork. At 1:00pm, at 1:10pm, at 1:20pm, at 1:30pm, etc. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: run a cron that executes the script every 10 minutes.

Comment: create a [cron-job](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: What OS? On most you can create a recurring timer. For example on Windows use Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: Sleep for 1 sec and check if it is time. Do your thing and mark the last time you uploaded as done.

Comment: Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715086/scheduling-python-script-to-run-every-hour-accurately) is another existing question about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Cron](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cron) to execute your script.

`*/10 * * * * python your_twitter_script.py`

If you want to do it with Python only, [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) or [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule#usage) are also a solution.

```py
import schedule
import time

def job():
    # twitter job

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!