# Automate API Request in Python

Tags: python, api

everyone. Hope someone can help me.

I have an API connection and I want to request/get and store (atualize my csv where the data is located) data hourly without using task scheduler from Windows.
Basically I want to schedule the python file to run at 6am, 7am, 8am, 9 and so on.

Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: You can run an infinite loop every minute. And run your code if conditions are met.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling Python Script to run every hour accurately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715086/scheduling-python-script-to-run-every-hour-accurately)

Answer (score 0):

There is a python module that does exactly that: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

But please be aware of this chapter: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#when-not-to-use-schedule.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do it with [Rocketry](https://rocketry.readthedocs.io/):

```
from rocketry import Rocketry
from rocketry.conds import daily

app = Rocketry()

@app.task(daily.at("06:00") | daily.at("07:00") | daily.at("08:00") | daily.at("09:00"))
def process_data():
    ... # Do the task

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

But that gets tedious, it seems you want it to run hourly between certain time which can be also achieved by:

```
from rocketry import Rocketry
from rocketry.conds import hourly, time_of_day

app = Rocketry()

@app.task(hourly & time_of_day.between("06:00", "09:00"))
def process_data():
    ... # Do the task

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Note:** `|` is *OR* operator and `&` is *AND* operator. The first argument in the `.task` is a condition that is either `True` or `False` (if `True`, the task will start).