# How to better work with time related commands in Python?

Tags: python, time, while-loop

Is there a better way to deal with a problem like this, avoiding some many useless comparisons?

```
import time

logClock = time.time()

while True:
    #Do something every 15 minutes
    if (time.time() - logClock) > 900:
        logClock = time.time()
        #Do something
```

Thank you!

Comment: sure but being uselessly executed several times. is there anything like a alarm clock or something?

Comment: You can use `time.sleep()` instead of `if` condition.

Comment: Tanveer - But that blocks possible remaining code to be executed right?

Comment: You need a separate thread that wakes up every 15 minutes to do something; in that thread you can let it sleep for the interval. As its not blocking the main thread you won't face this problem.

Comment: related: [Python Equivalent of `setInterval()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2697039/4279). Check out links I've provided there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a timer:

```
def wlanCheck():
    #Do something..

    #Timer controller...
    if util.getThreadKill() != 1:
        global tWLAN
        tWLAN = 0
        tWLAN = Timer(900, wlan.WLAN_check)
        tWLAN.start()

tWLAN = Timer(900, wlan.WLAN_check)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey while you **can** use an infinity loop with sleep, I would recommend to use [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Since your goal is to run a script every period of time, with Cron you can schedule scripts like that.

If I'm not worng this is what you need in you Cron jobs file:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script.py
```

When using Python you can do that with code-only via [python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab) lib.

Goodluck.

Comment: The OP  cannot use sleep as the OP wants the other code to continue