# How set a loop that repeats at a certain interval in python?

Tags: python, loops, time, timer

I'm new to python and I'm wondering if there's a function that would repeat an event at certain intervals, kinda like

```
setInterval()
```

in Javascript. I know I could just use

```
time.sleep()
```

inside a regular loop but I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will nead threads. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697039/python-equivalent-of-setinterval) (or others by searching on Google).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following is a simplified version of @Mathias Ettinger's

Because `call_at_interval` runs in a separate thread already, there is no need to use `Timer`, since it would spawn a further thread.

Just sleep and call the callback directly.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def call_at_interval(period, callback, args):
    while True:
        sleep(period)
        callback(*args)

def setInterval(period, callback, *args):
    Thread(target=call_at_interval, args=(period, callback, args)).start()

def hello(word):
    print("hello", word)

setInterval(10, hello, 'world!')
```

Comment: The interval here depends on the duration of callback, so won't be equal to the given argument and will fluctuate.

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Timer, Thread

def call_at_interval(time, callback, args):
    while True:
        timer = Timer(time, callback, args=args)
        timer.start()
        timer.join()

def setInterval(time, callback, *args):
    Thread(target=call_at_interval, args=(time, callback, args)).start()
```

The two functions are needed to avoid making `setInterval` a blocking call.

You can use it like so:

```
def hello(word):
    print("hello", word)

setInterval(10, hello, 'world!')
```

It will print `'hello world!'` every ten seconds.