# how to read the data periodically from mongoDB in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to read the data from mongoDB in every 5 minutes in python. I am able to read the data in using pymongo. But, thats one time. I want to establish mongoDB connection in every 5 minutes and look for new documents.

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test_insert
collection = db.dataset

for docs in db.dataset.find():
    print docs
```

But I have to manually do it. Can I make it sleep for 5 minutes and then again establish a connection with the database? 
Please help..

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697039/python-equivalent-of-setinterval

Comment: run a cron job for the script or run a linux screen with infinite loop and sleep time 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a scheduler.
I use `celery` for these kind of things, however it does more than this.

have a look at http://www.celeryproject.org/ and also http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: But how do I use it in my case? can you help?