# Is it possible to create a function in Python similar to the JS interval?

Tags: javascript, python

Is it possible to execute the code asynchronously in predefined intervals in Python like it's done in JS using the setTimer?

For example, the function example() will be called every 60 seconds in Python. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you should be able to do it using threads.

Comment: Run a thread that performs a loop that calls `example()` and then `os.sleep(60)`

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/q/2697039/2776525
Awesome username btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading

def printit():
  threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!"

printit()
```

the answer from: [Run certain code every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds)