# Why cant I use time module in python function

Tags: python

I was learning  about time module in python and I wanted to make a delay in my function like `setInterval` and `clearInterval`. I was trying to make something with time module but I cant run my code correctly.

I just want to make a simple `setInterval` and `clearInteval` and `setTimeout` with a simple code.

```
from threading import Timer
import time
run = True
def test():
    global run
    print("something")
    if run:
        Timer(1, test).start()
        time.sleep(2)

test()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide any code you made to attempt this problem

Comment: _but I cant run my code correctly_ How do you expect us to help, without seeing your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Equivalent of setInterval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697039/python-equivalent-of-setinterval)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: What is the expected output? The `time.sleep(2)` does work properly, but it isn't noticeable because you don't see anything run after it.

Comment: If you're having trouble with this code, you have to show us what the code did when you ran it, and say what results you were expecting.